# How to ignore whole folder in Android Studio version control?

Tags: git, android-studio, version-control, gitignore

I tried to ignore a folder in git (.idea/libraries), while using Android Studio, but I had no success, and there is no `ignore` in context menu, please check attached image[image]

Comment: Do you want to ignore your `.idea` folder ?

Comment: .idea or .idea/libraries

Answer (score 2):

Add a `.gitignore` file in your Project root (`Yad/`). Then add `.idea/libraries` in `.gitignore` file.

```
# at first remove git cached
$ git rm --cached .idea 

# ignore '.idea/libraries'
.idea/libraries

$ git status     # see git will ignore changes inside `.idea/libraries` folder
```

Answer (score 0):

This files and folders are default ignored by git in android studio:

```
*.iml
.gradle
/local.properties
/.idea/workspace.xml
/.idea/libraries
.DS_Store
/build
/captures
.externalNativeBuild
```

If you want to do changes, you can go to the project folder and modify `.gitignore` file.